# default text for foreign key in form in django

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-keys

I know that is the simple question but I have trouble with this
I have a table that shows colors and I used this as foreign key in Post table

```
class Post(models.Model):
    """docstring for Post"""

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1 )
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="write about your product")
    color=models.ForeignKey(Color)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

now when I want to show the form of `Post` to show the first row like this in color field
[image: in form page]

now I want to show choose color instead of `--------`.

Comment: You can override the choices in the ChoiceField of your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default the  widget used by ModelChoiceField will have an empty choice at the top of the list. You can change the text of this label (which is "---------" by default) with the empty_label attribute, or you can disable the empty label entirely by setting empty_label to None

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label)

Ex:

```
field1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=..., empty_label="(Choose color)")
```

Answer (score 2):

In your model form, you can use `__init__()` to initialize your form. Something like:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post_title', 'color')  # fields to show in your form

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['color'].empty_label = "Choose color"
```